# Calculating significance for multiple variations in AB testing in python

Tags: python, p-value, ab-testing, significance, visitor-statistic

Sorry if this is a basic question, I have been learning AB testing for couple of days now. 
For instance i have a table with visitors and purchases for four different versions of websites and

```
visitors|Purchases
21      | 3
180     |30
250     |50
100     |15
```

Is there a way that I can find the pvalue for this scenario in Python to find the significance of these tests?

TIA

Comment: Are you trying to check whether more visitors equals more purchases?

Comment: Yes. the four rows are four different versions and I am trying to check which image has more significance for more purchases

Comment: Since you only have 4 groups each with 1 record then you are pretty limited. A chi-square test will test whether all these values come from the same distribution, if you reject this null hypothesis then you can use a graph to determine which is likely to be the culprit, as for a p-value... not with data like these.